# Messed up slides in custom minimal JS/CSS slideshow

Tags: jquery, css

This JS/CSS slideshow works fine if the width of the container is the same as the width of the images (ie. 400px).

**But how to center the images horizontally while hiding the inactive slides if the container is larger or smaller than the images (ie. 800px or 200px)?**

```js
$('.slider').each(function() {
  var sliderWidth = $(this).outerWidth(),
    slides = $(this).find('.slide');

  changeSlide(1, slides, sliderWidth);
});

function changeSlide(i, items, sliderWidth) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var current = items.eq(i),
      previous = items.eq(i - 1);

    previous.css('left', -sliderWidth);
    current.css('left', 0);


    if (i < items.size() - 1) {
      changeSlide(i + 1, items);
    }
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.slider,
.slider .slides {
  position: relative;
}
.slider {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.slider .slides {
  z-index: 1;
}
.slider .slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.slider .slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: blue;
  left: 0;
}
.slider .slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: green;
}
.slider .slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: red;
}
.slider .slide img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: none;
}
/* * * * */

.large .slides {
  width: 600px;
}
.medium .slides {
  width: 400px;
}
.small .slides {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large">
    <h3>Width: 800px - FAIL</h3>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/ptx6qyydz/Untitled_1.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/aqra3fjqp/Untitled_1_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/kjg031fp1/Untitled_2.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/5tjvyellr/Untitled_2_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/sckwp2367/Untitled_3.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/x76k2k4at/Untitled_3_min.png" />-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="medium">
    <h3>Width: 400px - OK</h3>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/ptx6qyydz/Untitled_1.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/aqra3fjqp/Untitled_1_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/kjg031fp1/Untitled_2.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/5tjvyellr/Untitled_2_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/sckwp2367/Untitled_3.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/x76k2k4at/Untitled_3_min.png" />-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="small">
    <h3>Width: 200px - FAIL</h3>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/ptx6qyydz/Untitled_1.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/aqra3fjqp/Untitled_1_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/kjg031fp1/Untitled_2.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/5tjvyellr/Untitled_2_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/sckwp2367/Untitled_3.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/x76k2k4at/Untitled_3_min.png" />-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to center align the image.**
I see you tryed to do it with margin 0 auto, but you need a fixed size for that.
And we dont know the width of the image so use:
`text-align center`  on the container.
`dispaly: inline-block;` on the element
And `max-width:100%`
for the small one so you get a smaller image when the container is smaller then the image.

and now for the visible not **visibility** part.
**Dont use:** `$().hide();` <- wil mess up the animation
**Use:** `$().css('visibility','hidden');` <-- wil stil render the elements but transparent
and: $().css('visibility','visible');

```js
$('.slider').each(function() {
  var sliderWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
  var slides = $(this).find('.slide');
  slides.css('visibility','hidden');
  slides.first().css('visibility','visible');

  changeSlide(1, slides, sliderWidth);
});

function changeSlide(i, items, sliderWidth) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var current = items.eq(i);
    var previous = items.eq(i - 1);
    current.css('visibility','visible');

    previous.css('left', -sliderWidth);
    current.css('left', 0);


    if (i < items.size() - 1) {
      changeSlide(i + 1, items);
    }
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.slider,
.slider .slides {
  position: relative;
}
.slider {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.slider .slides {
  z-index: 1;
}
.slider .slide {
  text-align: center; /*for the big one*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.slider .slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: blue;
  left: 0;
}
.slider .slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: green;
}
.slider .slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: red;
}
.slider .slide img {
  display: inline-block; /*this if for the big one*/
  //margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%; /*this is for the really small one*/
}
/* * * * */

.large .slides {
  width: 600px;
}
.medium .slides {
  width: 400px;
}
.small .slides {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large">
    <h3>Width: 800px - FAIL</h3>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/ptx6qyydz/Untitled_1.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/aqra3fjqp/Untitled_1_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/kjg031fp1/Untitled_2.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/5tjvyellr/Untitled_2_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/sckwp2367/Untitled_3.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/x76k2k4at/Untitled_3_min.png" />-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="medium">
    <h3>Width: 400px - OK</h3>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/ptx6qyydz/Untitled_1.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/aqra3fjqp/Untitled_1_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/kjg031fp1/Untitled_2.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/5tjvyellr/Untitled_2_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/sckwp2367/Untitled_3.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/x76k2k4at/Untitled_3_min.png" />-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="small">
    <h3>Width: 200px - FAIL</h3>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/ptx6qyydz/Untitled_1.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/aqra3fjqp/Untitled_1_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/kjg031fp1/Untitled_2.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/5tjvyellr/Untitled_2_min.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/sckwp2367/Untitled_3.png" />
        <!-- Minimum image area: <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/x76k2k4at/Untitled_3_min.png" />-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to hide the inactive slides aswel?

Comment: Hey :) Yep. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: @MarkBoulder updated just for you :) now iwth visibility

Comment: Absolutely amazing!! Please allow me to buy you a beer next time I'm in Oslo because words alone can't express how thankful I am :)

Comment: @MarkBoulder im speachless... how how... just... what? Only people close to mer know these jokes.. and how it affects me as a Dutch Norweegan...